# Usage of LINQ or not for the price match algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

I have a JSON input with structure like this

```
"Levels": [
                    {
                        "Name": "3 - 50 Points",
                        "UnitPrice": 855,
                        "MinValue": 0,
                        "MaxValue": 51
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "51 - 100 Points",
                        "UnitPrice": 800,
                        "MinValue": 51,
                        "MaxValue": 100
                    },
                   {
                        "Name": "100- 150 Points",
                        "UnitPrice": 544,
                        "MinValue": 100,
                        "MaxValue": 150
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "150 Points",
                        "UnitPrice": 504,
                        "MinValue": 150,
                        "MaxValue": -1
                    }
                ]
```

And I have a class: -

```
public class Level {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public int MinValue { get; set; }

        public int MaxValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now my objective is to calculate the cost occurred based on an algorithm explained with example inside the method as code comments

```
public decimal GetCostOccured (int quantity, int minmaxflag, IEnumerable<Level> levels)
{
    // if quantity = 51 AND minmaxflag is 1 
    //then choose the [UnitPrice] where MaxValue is 
    //less than or equal to 51 which is 855. so cost is (51 * 855)

    //if quantity = 51 AND minmaxflag is 2 then 
    //choose the [UnitPrice]     where MinValue is 
    //less than or equal to 51 which is 800. so cost is (51 * 800)

}
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you giving us the JSON?  Are you also asking how to parse the JSON?

Comment: Your algorithm is incomplete. What happens if quantity is 200? Can you explain in words what minmaxflag is for?

Comment: JSON given  just to explain the example.

Comment: So if `minmaxflag` is 1 then you wan the `Level` with the largest `MaxValue` that is <= the `quantity`.  And if `minmaxflag` is 2 the same thing but with `MinValue`.  Then return either the `MaxValue` or `MinValue` (based on `minmaxflag`) times the `UnitPrice`?  What if `minmaxflag` is something other than 1 or 2?

Comment: @JLRishe edited the question. The range will always be contigous and the  quantity is bound to be withing the range. minmax is to ascertain if customer orders atleast 51 items or atmost 51 items.

Comment: @juharr minmax will be only 1 or 2 for sure. used to choose the [UnitPrice] accordingly.

Comment: @GilliVilla Then for `minmaxflag` of 2 shouldn't it be `MinValue` that is greater than or equal to 51 (at least 51)?

Comment: @juharr finally return [Quantity] times the [UnitPrice] of chosen level,

Comment: @juharr in the method we pass in the [Quantity] as first param....in my example I just used Quantity to be 51.

Comment: If quantity = 51 and minmaxflag is 2, then there are **two** entries where MinValue is less than or equal to 51. How do we know to choose the second one? Please _edit your question_ to _explain_ in words what this algorithm is supposed to do. Telling us the expected result for two specific inputs is not sufficient.

Comment: @JLRishe to answer your question we need to choose the level with [highest] of the *two* entries. And hence we choose the second one.  I am in the process of editing the qstn ...to be more clear...

Comment: Is that also true when minmaxflag is 1?

Comment: @JLRishe yes correct.

Comment: What should happen if quantity is 5 and minmaxflag is 2? There is no item where MaxValue is less than 2.

Comment: @JLRishe that situation of qty 5 and minmaxflag 2  will not occur per business rule. if quantity is 5 we default to first level. also the same applies for qty itself..there will be no qty less than 3.

Comment: Still waiting on a plain-English explanation of what this does. Could you tell us the expected result for the following pairs of qty/minmaxflag: 125/1, 125/2, 175/1, 175/2.

Comment: 125/1 & 125/2 both result in same (125 * 544). And 175/1 & 175/2 both result in [175 * 504). The only difference comes when there is the edge value itself is the quantity. In this case 51/1 , 51/2, 100/1, 100/2, 150/1 and 150/2 all have differennt values

Comment: And for the other two pairs of inputs? Is there a reason I have to extract information out of you one tiny piece at a time?

Comment: @JLRishe sorry for being a pain. The plain english explanation...I amtrying to put it in steps...for more clarity...though not achieving it totally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide the set of outputs you have described:

```
private static Level GetLevel(int quantity, int minmaxflag, IEnumerable<Level> levels)
{
    return minmaxflag == 1
        ? levels.Last(l => quantity > l.MinValue)
        : levels.Last(l => quantity >= l.MinValue);
}

public static decimal GetCostOccured(int quantity, int minmaxflag, 
                                     IEnumerable<Level> levels)
{
    return GetLevel(quantity, minmaxflag, levels).UnitPrice * quantity;
}
```

As far as I can tell, the way minmaxflag works is:

- 1 -> Pick range where `quantity` is in (MinValue, MaxValue]
- 2 -> Pick range where `quantity` is in [MinValue, MaxValue)

In other words, when `minmaxflag` is 1, the price decreases once `quantity` *exceeds* a threshold, whereas when `minmaxflag` is 2, the price decreases once `quantity` *meets* a threshold. Does that sound correct?